# Max and min from the column in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

[image]i have a table with the following data, i am trying to get the max and min columns from the table. if it is one column i can use max/min for the column, but here i am comparing all the column in a table. what i need is add new columns to store max and min data.

and there will be only one row in the table

```
create  table 
#test ( column1 int, column2 int , column3 int , column4 int ,column5 int,column6 int)

insert into #test
values( 89, 103,87,67,86,56)

select * from #test 

--drop table #test
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: you could unpivot the sequence (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) then take the max / min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is just cross applying the min/max values of the columns. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #test t 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(val), MIN(val) 
    FROM (VALUES (t.column1), (t.column2), (t.column3), (t.column4), (t.column5), (t.column6)) AS c(val)
) AS c(maxvalue, minvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the VALUES method to unpivot the data and then reaggravating it will make for a cleaner syntax but it does come with a cost to performance (not terrible but it is there). Using CASE expressions is a bit more cumbersome but in the syntax department, especially if there a lot of columns to be evaluated, but you won't incur the same performance penalty...

```
SELECT
    t.column1, t.column2, t.column3, t.column4, t.column5, t.column6,
    MinValue = CASE 
                    WHEN t.column1 <= t.column2 AND t.column1 <= t.column3 AND t.column1 <= t.column4 AND t.column1 <= t.column5 AND t.column1 <= t.column6 THEN t.column1
                    WHEN t.column2 <= t.column1 AND t.column2 <= t.column3 AND t.column2 <= t.column4 AND t.column2 <= t.column5 AND t.column2 <= t.column6 THEN t.column2
                    WHEN t.column3 <= t.column1 AND t.column3 <= t.column2 AND t.column3 <= t.column4 AND t.column3 <= t.column5 AND t.column3 <= t.column6 THEN t.column3
                    WHEN t.column4 <= t.column1 AND t.column4 <= t.column2 AND t.column4 <= t.column3 AND t.column4 <= t.column5 AND t.column4 <= t.column6 THEN t.column4
                    WHEN t.column5 <= t.column1 AND t.column5 <= t.column2 AND t.column5 <= t.column3 AND t.column5 <= t.column4 AND t.column5 <= t.column6 THEN t.column5
                    ELSE t.column6
                END,
    MaxValue = CASE 
                    WHEN t.column1 >= t.column2 AND t.column1 >= t.column3 AND t.column1 >= t.column4 AND t.column1 >= t.column5 AND t.column1 >= t.column6 THEN t.column1
                    WHEN t.column2 >= t.column1 AND t.column2 >= t.column3 AND t.column2 >= t.column4 AND t.column2 >= t.column5 AND t.column2 >= t.column6 THEN t.column2
                    WHEN t.column3 >= t.column1 AND t.column3 >= t.column2 AND t.column3 >= t.column4 AND t.column3 >= t.column5 AND t.column3 >= t.column6 THEN t.column3
                    WHEN t.column4 >= t.column1 AND t.column4 >= t.column2 AND t.column4 >= t.column3 AND t.column4 >= t.column5 AND t.column4 >= t.column6 THEN t.column4
                    WHEN t.column5 >= t.column1 AND t.column5 >= t.column2 AND t.column5 >= t.column3 AND t.column5 >= t.column4 AND t.column5 >= t.column6 THEN t.column5
                    ELSE t.column6
                END
FROM
    #test t;
```

Results...

```
column1     column2     column3     column4     column5     column6     MinValue    MaxValue
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
89          103         87          67          86          56          56          103
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4067/find-max-value-from-multiple-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/).

```
SELECT
    column1
    ,column2
    ,column3
    ,column4
    ,column5
    ,column6
   ,(SELECT MAX(MaxValue)
      FROM (VALUES (column1),(column2),(column3), (column4), (column5), (column6)) AS [Values](MaxValue)) 
   AS MaxValue
   ,(SELECT MIN(MinValue)
      FROM (VALUES (column1),(column2),(column3), (column4), (column5), (column6)) AS [Values](MinValue)) 
   AS MinValue
FROM #test
```